# Getting correct offset for timezone using current_timestamp in apache spark

Tags: java, apache-spark

I am new to both Java and Apache spark and trying to understand the timestamp and timezone usage. 
I would like all the timestamps to be stored in EST timezone in SQL Server from data i get from apache spark DF.

When I use current_timestamp, I am getting the correct EST time but the offset i am getting when i look at data is '+00:00' instead of '-04:00'.

Here is a value stored in database that is passed in from spark dataset:
`2020-04-07 11:36:23.0220 +00:00`

From what I see current_timestamp does not accept any timezone. Moreover, the time is correct (it is in EST) but i don't understand why the offset is wrong.

Any help to understand this would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Java `Timestamp`s work more or less as `LocalDateTime` in Java - they don't contain timezone information. And the database is interpreting this as UTC timestamp. That's why you got a mismatch. I usually use two approaches (depending what suits better)

1. You can return UTC timestamp from Spark (with simple custom UDF) instead of using `current_timestamp` which is timezone specific.
2. You can encode your dates as Strings - similarly, using `java.time` API you can achieve that with simple udf

Hope things are a bit clearer now.

Answer (score 0):

I convert the UTC default to Localtimezone as below

```
current_timestamp1 = current_timestamp(),
current_timestamp2 = from_utc_timestamp(current_timestamp, "Australia/Sydney")
```