# Does spark sql timestamp datatype actually store timezone?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

Does the spark sql `timestamp` data type actually store timezone?

I'm using databricks 6.5 (Apache Spark 2.4.5, Scala 2.11)

```
%sql

select 
current_timestamp C1,
from_utc_timestamp(current_timestamp,"Australia/Adelaide") C2,
date_format(from_utc_timestamp(current_timestamp,"Australia/Adelaide"),"Z") C3
```

Gives this result

```
C1                              C2                              C3
=====================================================================
2020-07-02T07:06:57.716+0000    2020-07-02T16:36:57.716+0000    +0000
```

There is no sign of a timezone designator anywhere

All the datetime functions I can find require you to designate a timezone. It seems to me that the timezone part should *not be displayed* because it's not actually there in the data.

This question says: no it's not stored but can anyone confirm?

[Getting correct offset for timezone using current_timestamp in apache spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61084442/getting-correct-offset-for-timezone-using-current-timestamp-in-apache-spark)

## Edit

Does anyone else think the +0000 is misleading here? To me it implies the date has a timezone of UTC, and concievably might be able to store a different timezone. I come from SQL Server world where a datetime that doesn't store a timezone doesn't have a timezone designator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In spark, all the datetime operations/functions are timezone aware but spark internally never store timezone, they store time in `int` and `long`

from spark doc -

```
* Helper functions for converting between internal and external date and time representations.
 * Dates are exposed externally as java.sql.Date and are represented internally as the number of
 * dates since the Unix epoch (1970-01-01). Timestamps are exposed externally as java.sql.Timestamp
 * and are stored internally as longs, which are capable of storing timestamps with microsecond
 * precision.
```

ref- [spark-git](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/util/DateTimeUtils.scala#L37)